# What could be the reason time info in ps command don't change while the process is active

Tags: linux, unix, process, aix

I'm running a java process (doing some database manipulations) and I ran `ps -lp 5631232`

```
   F   S  UID   PID      PPID     C PRI NI ADDR       SZ       WCHAN    TTY  TIME  CMD
202001 A  205  5631232  263213   0  60 20 3f46b46120 70156     *      pts/6  1:09 java
```

the 'TIME' has not been changed for a long while. The status is A (active), so I think it didn't halt.

I just don't know how can I find out what's going wrong out there? Anyone can tell me how to detect the problem and/or what could be the problem?

I'm using AIX system.

Comment: `TIME` is a measure of actual CPU time being used, not elapsed time since the process started. If the process is essentially idle, `TIME` will not increment much...

Comment: Does the cpu time take account for the database manipulations? Could it be majority of time was spent on disk i/o instead of cpu so that `TIME` is `ps` didn't change much?